# Is it possible to use GROUP and COUNT to obtain a list of one table, with a COUNT of records from a second table In ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Sorry for the vague question, I didn't know how to ask exactly.

Say you got two models, `Owner` and `Article`. An `Owner` can have many `Articles`. I want a list with the contents of the `Owner` model, along with the count of `Articles` that correspond to each `Owner`.

It'd look like this:

```
owner_id | Name | COUNT
-----------------------
|     1  | Tom  |  20
|     2  | Bob  |  10
|     3  | Karl |   5
|     4  | Bart |  24
|     5  | Zack |   0
```

Currently I've tried to do the following:

```
Owner.joins(:articles).select('id_owner, owner.name, COUNT(owner.id_owner)')
                      .group(:id_owner).order('count(articles.id_article) desc')
```

This works, but is there an easier way to express that with `ActiveRecord`? I feel that breaking it down to SQL in the `select` is kinda hacky, maybe there's no other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind adding one extra field `articles_count` to your `owners` table, then you could use AR's [`counter_cache`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache).

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Articles < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, counter_cache: true
end
```

Then, AR would update the `articles_count` column on `owners` table automatically and you'd always have a associated owner articles count without stressing your db.

As for your original question, I don't think AR has an interface that would allow you to *add* `COUNT(field)` field from another table to your model.

Comment: Interesting. Stressing the DB is exactly what I was trying to avoid. How would I access it from a controller? Owner.articles_count?

Comment: Simply by asking the `size` of your association `@owner.articles.size`.

Comment: Right, I meant to ask if there would be such a method, cause later it'd allow me to do something like `Owner.all.order(:articles_count)`.

Comment: Yeap, you can use `articles_count` just like any other normal table field.